# Python deepcopy uses more memory than needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, memory, deep-copy

Recently I came across strange memory usage while using `copy.deepcopy`.

I have the following code example:

```py
import copy
import gc
import os

import psutil
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
from humanize import filesize


class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ["name", "foos", "bars"]

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.foos = {}
        self.bars = {}

    def add_foo(self, foo):
        self.foos[foo.name] = foo

    def add_bar(self, bar):
        self.bars[bar.name] = bar

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {k: getattr(self, k) for k in self.__slots__}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        for k, v in state.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


class Bar(object):
    __slots__ = ["name", "description"]

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {k: getattr(self, k) for k in self.__slots__}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        for k, v in state.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

def get_ram():
    return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info()[0]

def get_foo():
    sub_foo = Foo("SubFoo1")
    for i in range(5000):
        sub_foo.add_bar(Bar("BarInSubFoo{}".format(i), "BarInSubFoo{}".format(i)))
    foo = Foo("Foo")
    foo.add_foo(sub_foo)
    for i in range(5000):
        foo.add_bar(Bar("BarInFoo{}".format(i), "BarInFoo{}".format(i)))

    return foo

def main():
    foo = get_foo()
    foo_size = asizeof(foo)

    gc.collect()
    ram1 = get_ram()

    foo_copy = copy.deepcopy(foo)

    gc.collect()
    ram2 = get_ram()
    foo_copy_size = asizeof(foo_copy)
    print("Original object size: {}, Ram before: {}\nCopied object size: {}, Ram after: {}\nDiff in ram: {}".format(
        filesize.naturalsize(foo_size), filesize.naturalsize(ram1), filesize.naturalsize(foo_copy_size),
        filesize.naturalsize(ram2), filesize.naturalsize(ram2-ram1)
    ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I tried to do, is to test the amount of memory used by the program before and after the `copy.deepcopy`. For this purpose, I created two classes.
I expected my memory usage to rise after the call to deepcopy in an amount equal to the size of the original object.
Strangly I got these results:

```
Original object size: 2.1 MB, Ram before: 18.6 MB
Copied object size: 2.1 MB, Ram after: 24.7 MB
Diff in ram: 6.1 MB
```

As you can see the difference in memory usage is aprox. 300% the size of the copied object.

** These results has been obtained using Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10 64 bit

What I tried?

- Running this example of code using Python2.7, the results was even stranger (more than 500% of the copied object size):

```
Original object size: 2.3 MB, Ram before: 34.3 MB
Copied object size: 2.3 MB, Ram after: 46.2 MB
Diff in ram: 11.9 MB
```

- Running on Linux using both Python3.8 and Python2.7 got the same results (respectively).
- Returning list of tuples instead of dict in `__getstate__` got better results but far from what I was expecting
- Using lists instead of dicts in the `Foo` object also got better results but also far from what I was expecting.
- Using `pickle.dumps` & `pickle.loads` in order to copy the object has produced the same results.

Any toughts?

Comment: some of that is probably accounted for beause `deepcopy` keeps a cache of all the objects it has visited to avoid getting stuck in an infinite loop. For this sort of thing, you should probably write your own efficient copy function. `deepcopy` is written to be able to handle arbitrary inputs, not necessarily to be efficient.

Comment: Copying increased RAM by 6.1 MB. How much did *creating the original* increase RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of that is probably accounted for because `deepcopy` keeps a cache of all the objects it has visited to avoid getting stuck in an infinite loop (a `set` I'm pretty sure). For this sort of thing, you should probably write your own efficient copy function. `deepcopy` is written to be able to handle arbitrary inputs, not necessarily to be efficient.

If you want an efficient copying function, you can just write it yourself. This is sufficient for a deep copy, something to the effect of:

```
import copy
import gc
import os

import psutil
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
from humanize import filesize


class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ["name", "foos", "bars"]

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.foos = {}
        self.bars = {}

    def add_foo(self, foo):
        self.foos[foo.name] = foo

    def add_bar(self, bar):
        self.bars[bar.name] = bar

    def copy(self):
        new = Foo(self.name)
        new.foos = {k:foo.copy() for k, foo in self.foos.items()}
        new.bars = {k:bar.copy() for k, bar in self.bars.items()}
        return new

class Bar(object):
    __slots__ = ["name", "description"]

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def copy(self):
        return Bar(self.name, self.description)

def get_ram():
    return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info()[0]

def get_foo():
    sub_foo = Foo("SubFoo1")
    for i in range(5000):
        sub_foo.add_bar(Bar("BarInSubFoo{}".format(i), "BarInSubFoo{}".format(i)))
    foo = Foo("Foo")
    foo.add_foo(sub_foo)
    for i in range(5000):
        foo.add_bar(Bar("BarInFoo{}".format(i), "BarInFoo{}".format(i)))

    return foo

def main():
    foo = get_foo()
    foo_size = asizeof(foo)

    gc.collect()
    ram1 = get_ram()

    foo_copy = foo.copy()

    gc.collect()
    ram2 = get_ram()
    foo_copy_size = asizeof(foo_copy)
    print("Original object size: {}, Ram before: {}\nCopied object size: {}, Ram after: {}\nDiff in ram: {}".format(
        filesize.naturalsize(foo_size), filesize.naturalsize(ram1), filesize.naturalsize(foo_copy_size),
        filesize.naturalsize(ram2), filesize.naturalsize(ram2-ram1)
    ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```